# jQuery how to select <foo.bar></foo.bar> node

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an XML document that looks someting like this:

```
<event>
    <foo.bar>content</foo.bar>
</event>
```

I use jQuery to read this xml document as follows:

```
var $xml = $( $.parseXML(xmlStr) );
```

When i try to select the foo.bar node, it will search for a node with the name foo and the class bar. How can i select this node by tagname?

```
$xml.find( "foo.bar" ) //returns nothing, searches for tag foo with class bar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `.` in the selector:

```
$xml.find("foo\\.bar")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use this:

```
$xml.find( "foo\\.bar" )
```

You need an escape character for the `.`.